# extract numbers from text in C++ --- segmentation fault

Tags: c++, text

I have a text containing numbers:148,147,148,146,135,22,.... with almost 11000 numbers. I want to put every odd -positioned number (the first, the third ...) in an array (148,148,135...) and every even-positioned number in another one (second, fourth ..., that is 147,146,22...). Running the following piece of code I get a segmentation fault error and I am not sure if numbers get properly in the arrays. Can you help?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;


 int main(){
 ifstream infile;
 int arraya[11000];
 int arrayb[11000];
 int i=0;
 int noum=0;
 char cNum[10];
            infile.open ("pairs.txt", ifstream::in);

            if (infile.is_open())
            {

                    while (infile.good())
                    {
                        infile.getline(cNum, 256, ',');
                        if ( i % 2== 0 )
                        arraya[i]= atoi(cNum); 
                        else
                        arrayb[i]= atoi(cNum) ;                 
                        i++ ;
                    }
                    infile.close();
            }
            else
            {
                    cout << "Error opening file";
            }

 for (i=0; i<10;i++){
 cout<<arraya[i];
 cout<<",";
 cout<<arrayb[i];}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a response but.. You are declaring int arraya[6000]; And you do arraya[i]= atoi(cNum); Without testing if i < 6000 Bad practice.

Comment: Post an input sample.

Comment: `while (infile.good()) { infile.getline` No no no no no no no no no no no

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
while (infile.good())
{
    infile.getline(cNum, 256, ',');
```

into

```
while (infile.getline(cNum, 10, ',')) {
```

since the size of `cNum` is only 10.

Also, as @synapse mentioned, you write over array boundaries. You need

```
if ( noum % 2== 0 )
    arraya[i/2]= atoi(cNum); 
else
    arrayb[i/2]= atoi(cNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    int arraya[6000];
    int arrayb[6000];
    int iA = 0;
    int iB = 0;

    int noum = 0;
    char cNum[10];
    infile.open("pairs.txt", ifstream::in);

    if (infile.is_open()) {

        while (infile.getline(cNum, 256, ',')) {

            noum = atoi(cNum);
            if (noum % 2 == 0)
                arraya[iA++] = noum;
            else
                arrayb[iB++] = noum;
        }

        infile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Error opening file";
    }
    cout << "Even: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < iA; i++) {
        cout << arraya[i];
        cout << ",";
    }

    cout << std::endl;

    cout << "Odd: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < iB; i++) {
        cout << arrayb[i];
        cout << ",";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a boolean variable that declares if the number is an even or an odd spot, it's also solvable by an iterator and checking if it % 2 == 0, this is just one of the applications:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream text;
    text.open("yourfile", ifstream::in);

    if (!text.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file.";
        return 1;
    }

    int arrayA[1000];
    int arrayB[1000];
    int iA = 0;
    int noum = 0;
    int iB = 0;
    bool odd = true;
    string cNum;
    while(text >> cNum) {
        noum = atoi(cNum.c_str());
        if (!odd) {
            arrayA[iA++] = noum;
            odd = true;
        } else {
            arrayB[iB++] = noum;
            odd = false;
        }
    }
    text.close();
    if (!odd)
        for (int i = 0; i < iA; i++)
            cout << arrayA[i] << ", " << arrayB[i] << endl;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < iB; i++)
            cout << arrayA[i] << ", " << arrayB[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```